# Detecting refresh event in GWT

Tags: gwt

We need to detect the Refresh event (f5) / reload of the web application. 
Is there an event in GWT that can detect this?

thanks,
mj

Answer (score 8):

Add a [Window Closing Handler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.ClosingHandler.html):

```
HandlerRegistration registration = Window.addClosingHandler(new ClosingHandler() {
    void onWindowClosing(ClosingEvent event) {
        // call the server, or whatever
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

The `HandlerRegistration` is used to deregister the `Handler` if you don't need it anymore.